# How Can I grab min Y for each X?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have dataframe which has 2 columns X, Y.

```
inv_trans_df = pd.DataFrame(inv_trans)
```

For each value of X, I have multiple Y.

How Can I grab min Y for each X and also plot this?

Comment: `plt.plot(df.groupby('X')['Y'].max())`? There are other ways too (probably faster if your dataframes are large). An example dataframe would help.

Comment: Thanks it worked